# Getting "file object does not exist" error in python django

Tags: python, django

I have a few objects where I have no file attached.

I have this code:

```
if os.path.isfile(object.pdf_file.url):
                object.url = object.pdf_file.url
            else:
                object.url = ""
```

But I am getting this error:

```
The 'pdf_file' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if os.path.isfile(object.pdf_file.url):
```

This will throw the error because you need the file to get the url. I do not think that will work even if the file exists since *isfile()* needs a path, not the url which is relative to your webserver/django-settings for media url not where it is located on your server.

Try:

```
if object.pdf_file:
    object.url = object.pdf_file.url
else:
    object.url = ""
```

This will work since the FileField will return None if it is null.